# Adding text inside a donut chart in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have a donut type chart created in SSRS which shows progress. I however have a % that i wanted to had in the middle of the document. Is there a way to add a text/rectangle in the center? I tried using one of the data label and converted it as an expression for the % but you can't move it to the center. Any possibilities?

[image]

Comment: Does this help https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/508b9651-a49a-4f27-bb93-bb284b5dd828/chart-type-shape-doughtnut-label-inside-the-doughtnut-hole?forum=sqlreportingservices

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but may help anyway...

As told in Dale's link, textboxes over charts are not supported.
I used a single radial gauge instead which allows inside centered label.
In order to rid off this old fashioned design, you'll have to customize a couple of properties in GaugePanel, RadialScale (min value=0 max value=100 sweepangle=360 startangle=180 hide tickmarks), RadialPointer (Placement=Cross Type=Bar Barstart=0 Needlestyle=SteelthArrow), add a label (right-click on the RadialGauge) and delete the RadialRange.
But see that [pretty good final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjw3m.png)

Comment: How did you add actual data to the gauge? for example, numbers from 4 columns.